# Specified cast not Valid when updating Item in ObservableCollection bound to Listview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugin.media.crossmedia

I am trying to add an image from the device to my App in Xamarin using https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin. The odd thing is, that adding the Item raises an exeption at some point "between the lines". I don't know how to debug this and assume it happens implementing  `OnPropertyChanged` wrong.

I wrapped the exeption in a Try/Catch Block and to my surprise learned that the Item has actually been added and `App.api.message.MediaFiles.Count()` has increased. This leads me to assume that the Exeption actually happes after but not at `.Add(Item)`.

This must either be the `OnPropertyChanged()` (But then why is the Debugger not showhing me that portion of code?) or the magic behind the scenes where Xamarin binds the Listview to `...Thumbnail`.

However since both of these options are relatively new to me a mistake or misinterpretation is quite likely here and any hint on how or where to investigate this would be appreciated.

Here's what I do in detail:

```
 [...]
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = App.api.message;
        Media.ItemsSource = App.api.message.MediaFiles;
      [...]
    }
```

The Listview in XAML :

```
[...]
<ListView x:Name="Media" BackgroundColor="#f1f1f1" HasUnevenRows="true" IsVisible="true" Header="Media" ItemTapped="RemoveImage" RowHeight="90" HeightRequest="120">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView> 
[...]
```

With `file` comming from picking or taking an image I do:

```
    public void AddFile(MediaFile file)
    { 
        Classes.MessageClass.Media Item = new Classes.MessageClass.Media();

        Item.Filename = file.Path;

        Item.Thumbnail = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStreamWithImageRotatedForExternalStorage();
            return stream;
        });

        file.Dispose();

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Item.Filename);
        Item.Size = fileInfo.Length;

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nOriginal File:{0} \n{1:###,###,###} Bytes\nCaption: {2}\nContent Type: {3}", Item.Filename, Item.Size, Item.Caption,Item.ContentType);

        try
        {
            App.api.message.MediaFiles.Add(Item);  //EXEPTION "Specified cast not Valid"
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exeption: " + ex.Message + " " + ex.Data.Values.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Attached Images: " + App.api.message.MediaFiles.Count());
        App.api.message.HasMedia = true;

        UpdateImagesUI();
    }
```

And finally my definition of `Classes.MessageClass.Media`. (I added values to outrule null-value issues):

```
public class Media
    {
        public string Caption { get; set; } = "";
        public string Filename { get; set; } = "";
        ImageSource thumbnail;
        public long Size { get; set; } = 0;
        public string ContentType { get; set; } = "";
        public bool IsVideo { get; set; } = false;
        public ImageSource Thumbnail
        {
            get
            { 
                return thumbnail;
            }
            set 
            { 
                if ((thumbnail != value) && (value != null))
                {
                    thumbnail = value;
                    Console.WriteLine("Image Updated");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Thumbnail");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

And `in MessageClass()`: `MediaFiles = new ObservableCollection<Media>();`

Finally the Stack:

```
 (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:288 
 at  System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, System.Object item, System.Int32 index) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:351 
 at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].InsertItem (System.Int32 index, T item) [0x00024] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:219 
 at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].Add (T item) [0x00020] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs:67 
 at SegelnBlogsEditor.MainPage.AddFile (Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile file) [0x0009e] in /Users/hinnerkweiler/wwwroot/SegelnBlogsEditor/SegelnBlogsEditor/MainPage.xaml.cs:292
```

Comment: what does the stack trace show?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @Jason. I attached the Trace to the Post above. Not really sure what to learn from that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageSource.FromStream` method takes an Action as parameter, which is evaluated every-time the ViewCell needs to be rendered. Using the `file` reference inside the action for later use and disposing it would cause exceptions.

**Edit:**

A better approach would be getting Image from file name

```
Image.Thumbnail = ImageSource.FromFile(Item.Filename);
```

Comment: Just for clearification. Does that mean in `Item.Thumbnail = ImageSource.FromStream(() ...` I am not returning the `stream` content to the property but the Action itself?

Comment: `ImagSource.FromStream` evaluates the Action and returns the stream. But the `file` object is already disposed, which case it throws exception, check the [MediaPlugin Source](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin/Shared/MediaFile.cs#L77)

Comment: Ok, I see that point. I actually turned to `Image.Thumbnail = ImageSource.FromFile(Item.Filename);`- originally as a work around because that way I risk to show a bunch of 50MB Images as thumbnails. Thank alot for point me to further readings.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you take a look at [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) library